# Windows XP doesn't install on a PC

Tags: windows-xp

When I try to install XP x32 and x64, theres just an underscore. I dont know why is it doing it. I wanted to dual boot XP and 10. I have 8GB of ram. I just wanted to know, can I atleast limit the ram to 2-3GB?

Comment: XP will not install on modern hardware, what make and model PC is it?

Comment: I have an Irbis PC, I cant read the model, because i would have to lift the PC, and look at the model. I have an AMD A8-5500 APU, R9-270. (EDIT: I actually had an HD7670)

Comment: Windows XP was only 32-bit.  There is an entirely different version of Windows, known as Windows XP 64-bit, but it's licensing and support was entirely seperate from Windows XP.  If you want to limit the system memory to 3 GB, is there a reason you are even attempting to run a 64-bit operating system, considering 3 GB is well within the limits of a 32-bit operating system?

Comment: This doesn't answer all of your questions but for windows xp (32bit), there is a [boot.ini flag](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/108393/the-maxmem-switch-in-the-windows-boot-ini-file) that will limit the memory it uses.  If you are using it in a VM, just tell the VM how much memory you want it to have.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion (in my view) is to make XP a virtual machine. That will work for sure (I have it here). XP will no longer run on new machines and that includes trying to use dual boot.